# generate service with generics in Spring

Tags: java, spring

if i have this code :

```
@Service
public class A<T extends I> {
    @Autowired
    T val; 
}

@Service
public class B1 implements I { }

@Service
public class B2 implements I { }

public interface I { }

@Service
public class C {
   @Autowired
   A<B1> subservice;
}
```

spring will complain that there are multiple candidates for A.val  .
Is there a solution for this except for explicitly building both of A's possible services?

Comment: You can use `@Qualifier` on the autowired field to specify the exact bean you need.

Comment: What happens if you convert to using constructor injection (which is preferable anyway)?

Comment: You're not forced to create to A subclasses (if that's what you're afraid of). You can simply make A a simple class with a constructor taking a T as argument, and add two methods like `@Bean
 public A<B1> a1(B1 b) {
  return new A<>(b);
 }` in your configuration.

Comment: @11thdimension it should be flexible depending if i need B1 or B2. With a qualifier i would bound myself to one specific B

Comment: @chrylis only the constructor does not change anything

Comment: @JBNizet I was also thinking of this but i wanted to know if i could get away with not doing this and if there is a way in spring to do this kind of thing automagically, but i guess there isn't

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way, no. The example in the documentation does use two separate subclasses: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-generics-as-qualifiers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with creating a bean for each combination since spring does not autowire with generics automatically.

For clarification spring uses the generics to decide which of the beans it has to use, but not to generate the object directly with the right generics.